# why are the dimensions on my Figma file so much bigger than it is meant to be when i try to apply them? is there a way to scale it down?

Tags: user-interface, frontend, scale, dimensions, figma

Okay so i have used Figma before, although it was long ago, i didnt have this problem. I am in a team of developers. we arent very good in designing so we paid a designer to do the design for us. Everything was all good till i started coding the landing page. The dimensions i got from Figma for basically everything is way too big and so unrealistic. I mean it told me that the height of the Navbar is 135px, 135?????? thats way too big for a Navbar. I have to scale it down myself and use trial and error method till it looks somewhat like the design. Normally i wouldnt complain if i was programming for myself but its not a personal project and i am on a deadline so the fact that i have to manually use trial and error method to make the designs match instead is just adding so much time that i didnt account for. Is this a fault of the designer or figma itself? is there a way to scale down the dimensions to make it browser-size ?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to understand is that if your screen has a higher resolution, it may look smaller or larger.

Second, your designer did his designs on a different scale.

You will have to make a system of scales. If he gave you the height as 135px and you think 80px is actually the correct value, your scale is 0.6 and all values should be passed as height x 0.6. Same way for the width.

The easiest way is for the designer to resize his design to the correct size. This will have only one drawback and that's he will have to edit multiple elements in each page individually and it can take hours. However, it's his mistake.